# How to customize JSF validation error message

Tags: validation, jsf, message, facelets

How can I customize the validation message that appears when validation fails?

Here is the code I have:

```
<h:form>
    <p><h:inputText
           id="userNo"
           title="Type a number from 0 to 10:">
       <f:validateLongRange
           minimum="3"
           maximum="6"/>
       </h:inputText>

       <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit"
           action="response"/>
    </p>
    <h:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false"
        id="errors1"
        for="userNo"/>
</h:form>
```

Currently the message looks like this:

```
j_idt10:userNo: Validation Error: Specified attribute is not between the expected values of 3 and 6.
```

Which is not particularly user-friendly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The simplest way would be to set the `validatorMessage="my custom message"` attribute in the `<h:inputText>` tag.

For a more advanced way read this article [Customize validation error message in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/)

[And here a complete Reference to all available message that you can override in JSF 2.0.x](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/branches/2.0.x/api/src/main/resources/javax/faces/Messages.properties)

Comment: It is surprising to me that there is no way to set the message "on-the-fly" in an attribute or something. Huh...

Comment: That definitely makes more sense. But what if I have more than one validator attached to the input and I want to customise the messages of each of them?

Comment: then you need to override the default message for each validator (in the Messages.properties file) like in the article I posted

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Daniel's answer you could always use the `label` attribute for your input components to remove the client-id (`j_idt10:userNo:`) from the error message.

E.g. with

```
<h:inputText id="userNo" title="Type a number from 0 to 10:"
             label="User number">
  <f:validateLongRange
           minimum="3"
           maximum="6"/>
</h:inputText>
```

will produce:

> User number: Validation Error: Specified attribute is not between the
>   expected values of 3 and 6.

The label attribute can be an el expression as well to change this part of the error message dynamically.

Answer (score 8):

You can use validatorMessage property of input text. Use requiredMessage property for required message, it is different from validator message.

```
<h:input text required ="true" validatorMessage="Enter user friendly message">
    <f:validateLongRange
        minimum="3"
        maximum="6"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Description added