# JSF: Different validation message for different validator tags?

Tags: validation, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

In my JSF+Primefaces application. I am using JSF validators tags to validation the input of text box

```
<p:inputText value="#{createAccessPrivilegeBean.name}" id="name" label="name" size="55" required="true"
    requiredMessage="#{messages.requiredError}" validatorMessage="#{messages.alphaNumericError}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="#{validatorBean.accessprivilegeValidator}"></f:validateRegex>
    <f:validateLength maximum="10"></f:validateLength>
</p:inputText>
```

Now for required message I had specified the message in requiredMessage attribute for all other validation tags I am using common message is coming which I have defined in validatorMessage attribute.

I need separate message for different validation like if validateRegex failed I need different validation message or  if validateLength fails I need different validation message.

how Can I do that ??

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10411840/617373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link for the solution:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/

Thanks to Daniel.

Comment: But what about the case when I have 3-4 similar inputs? How to understand which of them is wrong?