# primefaces p:fileUpload validation always shows default

Tags: validation, file-upload, primefaces

I don't know how to custom validate primefaces p:fileUpload.

My code xhtml is:

```
<h:form id="agruparCVForm" styleClass="validacionform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" escape="false"/>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dtPadding_bottom">
                <p class="parrafoMargintop1em textSmall">
                    <h:outputText value="#{comunidadesBundle.textoAdjuntarDocumentoAsociar}" escape="false"/>
                </p>
                <p:fileUpload value="#{agruparComunidadController.comunidadAAgrupar.documentoAutorizacion}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" required="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="float-cleaner marginTopBottom2em"></div>
    <!-- Botones-->
    <div class="ftr">
        <h:commandButton value="#{comunidadesBundle.guardarCambiosBtn}" title="#{comunidadesBundle.guardarCambiosBtn}" action="#{agruparComunidadController.agrupar}" styleClass="buttonContrast azul textSmaller MarginBottom2em floatRMobile"/>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

The action="#{agruparComunidadController.agrupar}" never gets  called as the jsf validation is performed before getting the standard message from the api.

The question is how can I put a customized error message? 
I'm new to primefaces and I don't know how it gets valiated.
I need to validate this field when the form get's submitted. So it should check if the field is empty and display the custom message instead of the standard message choose:.....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411773/how-to-customize-jsf-validation-error-message (including the links in it)

Comment: I've already read it. But, I only makes sense if you want to overrride a message from the Api. You are replacing for example: javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM={1}: Validation Error
but it will show this message through all the application.
 For example where is the error message in the API for not leaving the upload field empty?