# individual error message for each jsf validator tag

Tags: validation, jsf

I have an input field which must meet the following restrictions: the input data should have exactly 2 characters, it should accept only letters and numbers, and it must be uppercase. So far, i did the following:

```
<h:inputText id="code" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="2" />
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Z0-9]*$"/>
</h:inputText>
```

However, **i need individual error messages when any of these validations fails**. I did some search, and i found the following UNsuitable solutions:

1)  [How to customize JSF validation error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411773/how-to-customize-jsf-validation-error-message) : Providing an `validatorMessage` attribute inside the text tag  won't do the job, because this way i can provide only one message per input text tag.

2) http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.ro/p/validation-in-jsf.html : Validation method in the backing bean, or imperative validation using `@FacesValidator` annotation, are not good because this is exactly what i try to avoid; i want to move validation from back-end to front-end

3) https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/ : overriding the error message in `messages.properties` is not good for two reasons: 1. I want to use custom error messages only locally (page scope), not for the entire application. 2. I have the same validator tag occuring twice - but with different patterns, and i want a different error message for each situation

The documentation for the validation tags (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateLength.html) specifies no attribute such as 'message', or 'errorMessage', as I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tFied Kt but I think a woraround will be to place the custom overridden validation messages in a locale specific (which can be used only for this case ) properties file and use locale attribute of f:view tag to set the locale at the page level so that the messages are displayed from the locale specific message bundle.

Comment: nice idea, but unfortunately i couldn't make it work; in the jsf i put `<f:view locale="ko">`, then i created the file messages_ko.properties, and i placed it in various locations like the jsf folder, the backing bean's folder, but still, when the validation error triggers, i get the default error message, not the overridden one

Comment: Ok, did try placing it in the resources folder ?

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to concatenate all error messages into one big message. In case any validation fails, the corresponding message is anyway included in the big message.

So i made use of the `validatorMessage` attribute in the `inputText` tag.
Also, in order not to get the large message multiple times (when more than one of the validations fails) i replaced the 3 validations with an equivalent one:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Z0-9]{2}$"/>
```